# Django rolling back migration doesn't do anything. Table is still present

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I am running the following command to rollback my migration in my Django project.

```
python manage.py migrate users 0021_emailsetting
```

The issue is that there is no effect after this command is executed. I get following result:

```
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0021_emailsetting, from users
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

The table is still there in the database and `showmigrations` also checks that particular migration as applied.

I had applied `python manage.py migrate users zero` to make sure there isn't any previous migration causing the issue but the issue still remains after running all migrations after full rollback.

Comment: If the last migration applied is 0021, then run `manage.py migrate users 0020` to roll back migration 0021.

Comment: AAAH, My bad.  I see. Got it working

Comment: Best to think of it as time travel, not as undo or rollback. Reversing migrations lets you go back in time to the point you want to. You then automatically will think of the migration you need to provide as argument.